# All Javascript on site performs horribly Slow in Firefox 4 when transparent PNG's are present on the page

Tags: javascript, performance, wordpress, firefox, optimization

**ETA UPDATE: I've found that if I remove all the transparent .png files from my site, there are about 5, it runs fine. THAT is odd. And up-votes would be very helpful, I tested it on a few more computers, and *4/15* have this issue. Thanks! Any ideas?**

Runs fine on PC Firefox and all other browsers, but on 4/15 computers in Mac Firefox, the Javascript is just terribly slow, specifically the menubar. I tested them both outside the site and they worked fine. This has been an ongoing problem for quite some time, no idea how to solve it. Updated, problem goes away if I remove transparent PNG's from the site, like the banner in the top left.

My site: http://thenozzle.net/

All of the javascript is a bit slower then in other browsers, the two largest ones are menubar and video player. I can't ignore it at this point.

I'm wondering if it's something wordpress is adding, because the js works fine elsewhere.

Any ideas?

ETA: Here's my JS file:

http://thenozzle.net/wp-content/themes/twentyten/scripts.js

ETA: Here's my menubar code

```
$(function() {
    $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
        var $elem = $(this);
        $elem.find('img')
             .stop(true)
             .animate({
                'width':'170px',
                'height':'170px',
                'left':'0px'
             },400,'easeOutBack')
             .andSelf()
             .find('.sdt_wrap')
             .stop(true)
             .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
             .andSelf()
             .find('.sdt_active')
             .stop(true)
             .animate({'height':'170px'},300,function(){
            var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
            if($sub_menu.length){
                var left = '170px';
                if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                    left = '-170px';
                $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
            }
        });
    }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
        var $elem = $(this);
        var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
        if($sub_menu.length)
            $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');

        $elem.find('.sdt_active')
             .stop(true)
             .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
             .andSelf().find('img')
             .stop(true)
             .animate({
                'width':'0px',
                'height':'0px',
                'left':'85px'},400)
             .andSelf()
             .find('.sdt_wrap')
             .stop(true)
             .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Works fine for FF4 on Win7. My connections slow at the moment, so the video took some streaming, but wasn't slow or anything. Same with the menu

Comment: Not of much help, I know, but I just tried it Firefox 4 on Windows XP and it looks like it works perfectly.

Comment: Use Firefox's profile manager to create a new, bare profile -- without add-ons and only the plugins your site needs (you can keep multiple profiles).  Also download and run something like [ccleaner](http://www.google.com/search?q=ccleaner+mac). ... ... Firefox may just need a good "cleaning"/compacting, or some add-ons may be gumming the works.

Comment: Anyone? This is a huge problem, a vote up would help!

Comment: The menu works okay on Firefox 4 on Linux on my computer, the video loads quite slow but plays okay (but do you think that's related to javascript?). The menu is a lot smoother in Chrome but still quite useable. Maybe you're using some javascript feature that is especially slow in the Mac implementation of Firefox, see if there's any bug report about this...

Comment: I fixed the video, working better now. Still concerned about the menubar, I'll post the code, there isn't TOO much of it...

Comment: I was hoping it would run better with the new Firefox 5, it doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, it runs fine in FF5 on my system, but I'm running windows so maybe it's mac specific. On a side note, all those title's keep popping up when I'm over the menu and it's getting annoying :/. It's not as bad in firefox, but on chrome they come up instantly on hover...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you may have a some slighty corrupted PNGs.

Suggest you try the following: resave the PNGs out of photoshop. Save both PNG-24 and PNG-8. Test .

I have seen this before with PNGs that did not quite save correctly.

I tested the site on two macbooks pros one a core duo 2 and the other a core duo. Both ran fine the menu was very responsive even while the video was playing.

Assuming you have one the other steps listed in other answers here on the "suspect macs) ( ie created new accounts and tested ) then i think you need to look at what else makes those Macs different ? What version of OS X ? What model ( ie macbook vs Macbook pro vs Air etc )

Comment: I tested this on two Macbook pros a Core duo and a core 2 duo. Everything ran fine for me . I tried Safari and Firefox 4.0

Comment: Tested more macs. This have taken so much of my time, 4/22 now experience the problem. Still too many.

Comment: FINALLY SOLVED IT!!!!! YESSS!!!!! I removed the trouble-causing png files, completely re-made them in photoshop with the same dimensions, but this time I didn't compress them using ImageOptim, a mac app for losslessly compressing images on the fly. ImageOptims png-crush was doing something that cause javascript effects to slow way down then moving divs over the png files. FIXED, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 4.0 on Mac should be using OpenGL for hardware acceleration, while FF on Windows uses Direct2D. Since the problem is only occuring on some Macs, could it have something to do with their graphic card chipset - perhaps compare the specifications of the offending Macs, and also try to disable hardware acceleration to see if problems go away?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Never even thought of that. I'll test this afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new Firefox profile so you can run it with no extensions, addons, etc. installed. It may be that some extension (AdBlock, GreaseMonkey, etc.) is conflicting with some of the scripts in your page somehow.

I just tested it in FF4 on my Mac (MacBook Pro, 10.6.7) and it loaded up quickly, so it may just be something in your setup.

Comment: It was a good idea, but it did nothing. I've tested on 10 MacBooks, and two of them have the problem. I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Hm. Have you tried creating a brand new user account on one of the MacBooks showing the problem and testing it there to eliminate the possibility of something else running on the system conflicting? Probably a bit of overkill, but if nothing else is working, you might try that.

Comment: I actually tried that, no difference. I've got a recent MacBook, into core 2 duo, 4 GB of RAm, good video card, should work fine!

Comment: You might want to try stripping out components and re-testing, then. Try completely removing the video and refresh, see what happens. Do the same for the Navbar, see what happens. See if you can isolate one specific piece of the page that's causing problems. It's a bit of a painful process, but might help you track down a trouble area.

Comment: Used Scottie's idea. It's these transparent PNG's. If I remove them all, menubar works fine. If I remove then one at a time, it progressively gets better until they're all gone.

UPVOTES HELP. Please.

Comment: Try running all of your PNGs through http://www.smushit.com - it'll reduce the file size on all of them and re-save them. Dunno if that'll help, as none of your images are particularly huge, but you never know. Smaller images is always better, anyways.

Comment: I've compressed every PNG for lossless, don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

I would first validate the HTML, as it's possible that HTML tags could be going unclosed, producing weird behaviour with javascript. Validate your HTML and use Firebug to help you.

After that, I would try using a different spacer [such as this one](http://www.loremipsum.net/pixelgif/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try tomorrow morning and if they work, I'll award you 50 reps!

Comment: Validated html, it checks out now. Only one error where I missed the 'd' in 'width'. Nothing unclosed. The only pixel spacer that was loading on the site was the one from Google Analytics, and even with the GA script nulled out, the pixel spacer gone, the menubar is still very slow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if firefox has the same problem, but I know that if you tile small transparent png (like 1x1), it cause memory leak in ie7. Using a larger image fix it.

Comment: As in my comment on @desbest's post, I tried nulling Google Analytics that was loading the spacer png, it still runs very slowly.